# Virtualenv hook.log

Tags: permissions, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

My team uses virtualenvwrapper to manage the virtualenvs for our projects. However, it seems our hook.log group permissions keep getting changed to an individual user instead of keeping the shared group that all users have (in our case, www-data). Anyone have experience with this?

Here's the error that I get when I try to source virtualenvwrapper.sh:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 83, in main
    backupCount=1,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 118, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 65, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 24, in _open
    rtv = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler._open(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/env/hook.log'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
```

Comment: Maybe this can point you in the right direction: [https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/62/](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/62/)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I installed virtualenvwrapper using apt-get. Somehow when you install it using apt-get, it limits the permissions to the current user. To fix this, just remove it first using apt-get remove and reinstall using pip install for root user.